# How to configure NearCache with Hazelcast 3.5 without an explicit Client

Tags: configuration, hazelcast, near-cache

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30890393/66686), I'm trying to switch to the version 3.5-EA of Hibernate.

Up to now I had a configuration like this:

```
CacheConfiguration<K, V> configuration =  new CacheConfig<K, V>()
    .setNearCacheConfig(new NearCacheConfig().setInMemoryFormat(InMemoryFormat.OBJECT))
    .setExpiryPolicyFactory(createExpiryPolicyFactory(expiryDuration));
cache = cacheManager.createCache(cacheName, configuration);
```

But now the `setNearCacheConfig` method is gone. There only exists a `addNearCacheConfig` on the `ClientCacheConfig`. But I don't have a `ClientCacheConfig`.

I basically don't know where to put the `NearCacheConfig`.

Answer (score 0):

the configuration of the nearcache can be done on the client side. http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.5/manual/html-single/hazelcast-documentation.html#hazelcast-java-client

Comment: I know, but as I wrote in the question I don't have (and don't want) a separate client.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use xml for configuration (http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html-single/hazelcast-documentation.html#near-cache) - you could probably do something like this -

```
    Config cfg = new Config();
    MapConfig mc = new MapConfig();
    mc.setNearCacheConfig(new NearCacheConfig());
    cfg.addMapConfig(mc);
    HazelcastInstance hi = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(cfg);
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my opinion, NearCache feature is useful when you are using Client-Server hazelcast api and when youa re trying to access cache externally, but if you are gonna make call within hazelcast cluster internally and do not want to use Hazelcast client api than there no need to use NearCache feature.
Since there will not be any benefit out of it.